# Expose a function to docpad.coffee through a plugin

Tags: docpad

I'm trying to write a docpad plugin that exposes email-obfuscation functions.

At the moment I have this:

```
extendTemplateData: ({templateData}) ->
  templateData.obfuscate = (emailAddress) ->
     return ### obfuscated ### emailAddress
```

Great, I can now use `<%- @obfuscate(mail) %>` in my eco templates.

But, what I would like to do is something like this

```
docpadConfig:
   templateData: 
      emailAddresses:
         support: obfuscate("support@mycompany.com")
```

So I can write `<%- @emailAddresses.support %>`

I would also be ok with:

```
support: -> return obfuscate("support@mycompany.com")
```

So the question is: how can I make the obfuscate function available in that spot?

I've also tried to access it through `docpadConfig.templateData.obfuscate()` with no luck.

Comment: Where did you put the "extendTemplateData:"?  I'm trying to do the same thing as what you have here, but I'm confused where to place that function.  Is it in a plugin you wrote?

Comment: It's a docpad event. See here http://docpad.org/docs/events under 'available events'. I've used it in a plugin, source: https://github.com/bertvh/docpad-plugin-emailobfuscator/blob/master/src/emailobfuscator.plugin.coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close! You can get the plugin `templateData` like this:

```
templateData:
    emailAddresses:
        support: -> docpad.pluginsTemplateData.obfuscate("some test")
```

Comment: This works.. Where did you find this? Not in the documentation I presume.

Comment: I usually find these hidden things in the source at https://github.com/bevry/docpad and/or debugging using node-inspector - https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

The line that helped this issue is here:
https://github.com/bevry/docpad/blob/master/src/lib/docpad.coffee#L590